# How to stop Resource #100 folder being created when Joomla component gallery is viewed

Tags: php, resources, joomla, components

I have created a basic component for Joomla that allows users to list an item along with some associated images. When the page containing the gallery is viewed a strange folder is created in the root web directory in the format of Resource id #100, the number varies with each item. I have narrowed down the code that is causing this to the following. My question is can some see what I'm doing to cause this and can anyone offer alternatives to the code I'm using to read the files from a particular directory and return the information.

```
<p id="sl_gallery">
            <?php if( is_file( JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_eg/images/gallery/'.$this->eg->id.'/main.jpg' ) ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo JURI::root().'/components/com_eg/images/gallery/'.$this->eg->id.'/main.jpg' ?>" alt="myimage">
            <?php else: ?>
            <img src="<?php echo JURI::root().'/components/com_eg/images/nolistings.gif'; ?>" alt="myimage" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php
            $TrackDir= opendir(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_eg/images/gallery/'.$this->eg->id.'/second/');
            $count = 0;
            if ( !JFolder::exists($TrackDir) ) { JFolder::create($TrackDir); }
                while (($file = readdir($TrackDir)) !== false) {
                    if ($file == "." || $file == "..") { }
                    else {
                        ?>
                       <img src="<?php echo JURI::root().'/components/com_eg/images/gallery/'.$this->eg->id.'/second/'.$file; ?>" alt="myimage" />
                    <?php
                    }
                }
            closedir($TrackDir);  ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$TrackDir= opendir(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_eg/images/gallery/'.$this->eg->id.'/second/');
$count = 0;
if ( !JFolder::exists($TrackDir) ) { JFolder::create($TrackDir); }
```

...to this:

```
$TrackDirPath = JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_eg/images/gallery/'.$this->eg->id.'/second/';
if ( !JFolder::exists($TrackDirPath) ) { JFolder::create($TrackDirPath); }
$TrackDir = opendir($TrackDirPath);
$count = 0;
```

`$TrackDir` holds the result of a call to `opendir()` - this means it will either be a resource or `FALSE`. When you convert a resource to a string, it results in `Resource id #` - which you did by (effectively) passing it to `mkdir()`.

I have stored the path as a string in a variable `$TrackDirPath`, and passed that to `JFolder::create()` instead. I have also re-ordered the statements, to make sure that the directory exists before you try to open it.

Comment: Thanks Dave you explained that very well and now I understand what I was doing wrong.